# How can I make changes to others project Github?

Tags: git, github

I am working with teammates, and i create a repository for our team project. Now I know how to upload my part of code to github, but how Can My teammates contribute to my repository? (Assume they granted the privilege.)

E.g. There are 3 parts for our project, i will finish 1 part, the others will finish 2 parts, How can they upload and compare automatically to my repository?

Comment: You can find something similar discussed in this link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156519/managing-multiple-people-working-on-a-project-with-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually, I am new on github
>   ...
>   How can they upload and compare automatically to my repository

This is the basic flow of git:

- Create your git repo (which you already did)
- Add your co workers as contributes to your project.

  1. Navigate to the repository on Github you wish to share with your collaborator.
  2. Click on the `Settings` link in the right side menu, below `Network`
  3. On the new page, click the `Collaborators` menu item on the left side of the page.
  4. Start typing the new collaborator's GitHub username into the text box.
  5. Select the GitHub user from the list that appears below the text box.
  6. Click the `Add` button.
- Each one of your co workers need to `clone` the project
- Make changes to your code and commit them
- `push` the changes to GitHub

Read this out: http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for basic help with using git.  Your teammates and you can all use the `git pull` command to pull in changes (commits) from the GitHub repo and `git push` to push changes to the GitHub repo.  That is how you can see eachother's changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for relying so fast!. Actually, I am new on github. our goal is all changes to one reo? Could we do that?

Comment: Yes.  When you pull changes from a repo, it merges all the changes in that repo with all the changes you made locally (if a merge is required).  Then you can push your changes (and the merge commit) back to the repo.

Answer (score 1):

In multiple ways. I recommend that first you decide your iteration flows. A couple of ways are:

- They can clone your repo in their local machines and push changes to the remote repo. They can add remote branches for features in the remote repository and each feature can later be merged to the master branch once reviewed and accepted
- They can fork your project in github and make their changes in their copy of the repo and then use pull requests in github to your repository and your team can review changes prior to accepting the requests.

Here are a couple of tutorials to get you started:

- From [Github](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)
- [Forking a Project](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/)